# Partial derivatives of a function which is constant on the diagonal

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Suppose that $f:\mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}_+$ is a non negative smooth function such that it vanishes only on the diagonal, i.e., $f(x,y)=0$ iff $x=y$. Is it true then that $$\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}f(x,y)\right]_{x=y}=\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial y_i}\frac{\partial}{\partial y_j}f(x,y)\right]_{y=x}?$$

Comment: You understand that the second derivatives operators $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial y_i}\frac{\partial}{\partial y_i}$ to be different?

Comment: @Elias: I understand that the second derivatives need not be same at all points. But here since the function is same on the diagonal, I was wondering whether those second derivatives should be equal on the diagonal. Could you please give a counter example if you think those derivatives need not equal on the diagonal? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement is **True**, and actually we can conclude a little bit more:

> **Claim:** Suppose that $f:\Bbb R^n\times\Bbb R^n\to [0,+\infty)$ is smooth and  $f(x,y)=0$ iff $x=y$. Then for any $x\in \Bbb R^n$ and any $1\le i, j\le n$, we have 
>   $$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}(x,x)=\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y_i\partial y_j}(x,x) =-\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i\partial
> y_j}(x,x)=-\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_j\partial y_i}(x,x).$$

**Proof:** Define 
$$g(u,v)=f(u+v,u-v).$$
By definition, for $(x,y)=(u+v,u-v)$,

$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial u_i}(u,v)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(x,y)+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y_i}(x,y),\quad\frac{\partial g}{\partial v_i}(u,v)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(x,y)-\frac{\partial f}{\partial y_i}(x,y).$$

Denote 
$$A_{ij}=\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i\partial x_j},\quad B_{ij}=\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i\partial y_j},\quad C_{ij}=\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y_i\partial y_j}$$
for short. It follows that

$$\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial u_i\partial u_j}(u,v)=A_{ij}(x,y)+B_{ij}(x,y)+B_{ji}(x,y)+C_{ij}(x,y),\tag{1}$$

$$\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial u_i\partial v_j}(u,v)=A_{ij}(x,y)-B_{ij}(x,y)+B_{ji}(x,y)-C_{ij}(x,y).\tag{2}$$

From $f\ge 0$ and $f(x,y)=0$ iff $x=y$ we know that $g\ge 0$ and $g(u,v)=0$ iff $v=0$. Therefore, each point $(u,0)$ is a minimal value point of $g$, so 
$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial u_i}(u,0)=0\Longrightarrow \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial u_i\partial u_j}(u,0)=0,\tag{3}$$
$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial v_j}(u,0)=0\Longrightarrow \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial u_i\partial v_j}(u,0)=0.\tag{4}$$

Denote 
$$a_{ij}=A_{ij}(x,x),\quad b_{ij}=B_{ij}(x,x),\quad c_{ij}=C_{ij}(x,x)$$
for short, so we aim at proving $a_{ij}=c_{ij}=-b_{ij}=-b_{ji}$. Combining $(1)$ and  $(3)$ or combining $(2)$ and $(4)$, we have
$$a_{ij}+b_{ij}+b_{ji}+c_{ij}=a_{ij}-b_{ij}+b_{ji}-c_{ij}=0\iff a_{ij}+b_{ji}=b_{ij}+c_{ij}=0.$$
Noting that $a_{ij}=a_{ji}$ and $c_{ij}=c_{ji}$, the conclusion follows. $\qquad\square$

Comment: Thank you for the nice answer.

Comment: @Ashok: You are welcome!

Comment: Can you tell me the motivation behind the substitution $(x,y)=(u+v,u-v)$?

Comment: @Ashok: English is not my native language, so let me try if I can make my point clear. Since each point on the line $x=y$ is a minimal value point of $f$, the gradient of $f$ vanishes on the line $x=y$. To obtain some information of second order partial derivatives of $f$ from this, it would be convenient if we can introduce some change of variables $(x,y)\leftrightarrow(u,v)$, so that the condition $x=y$ can be  expressed as $v=$some constant, say $0$.

Comment: @Ashok: You can see the benefit of doing this from  Equations $(3)$ and $(4)$ in my answer; the information of second order partial derivatives of $g$ is much clearer. Therefore, one natural choice is $v=c(x-y)$ for some constant $c$. Then a natural choice of $u$ is to let it be "orthogonal" to $v$, i.e. $u=c'(x+y)$ for some constant $c'$. To make the calculation  simple, a good choice is $c=c'=\frac{1}{2}$. Geometrically, the $(u,v)$ coordinates are obtained from (up to some rescaling) rotating $(x,y)$ coordinates by $\frac{\pi}{4}$, which turns the line $x=y$ to the line $v=0$.

Comment: One more question in this regard. Is it easy to prove from these facts that the matrix $G=[g_{i,j}]$ with entries $g_{i,j}=-\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i\partial y_j}(x,x)$ is positive definite?

Comment: @Ashok: Do you mean $-G$? Clearly $-G$ is positive semi-definite, but it could have zero eigenvalue, or even it could be $0$-matrix. For example, $f(x,y)=\sum_i(x_i-y_i)^4$, $G(0,0)=0$.

Comment: No, I mean $G$ with $g_{i,j}=-\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i\partial y_j}(x,x)$. Please note the differentiation w.r.t. $y_j$ and then w.r.t. $x_i$ which is equal to $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}(x,x)$.

Comment: @Ashok: Sorry, I misread your notation of $g_{ij}$. Then $G$ is positive semi-definite and could have zero eigenvalue.

Comment: Can you give me a hint (or an outline) to the proof? Thank you.

Comment: @Ashok: Fix $x_0$ and consider the function $h(x)=f(x,x_0)$. $h$ has a minimum value at $x_0$, so its Hessian at $x_0$, which coincides with $G(x_0,x_0)$, must be positive semi-definite. Do you know this fact?

Comment: Oh yes! That simple! I should have figured that out. I knew the key would be your result that $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}(x,x)=\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y_i\partial y_j}(x,x) =-\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i\partial
y_j}(x,x)=-\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_j\partial y_i}(x,x)$. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Ashok: You are welcome.